# C++ programming assignment that is collecting input ,making a count and showing results in a list or table

Tags: c++

I am working on a program that collects input from users and creates a list with results. The program also has to make a count of the choices and make a simple calculation.
So far I have this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct emp{
  char name[20];
  char choice[20];
}obj[2];

int main(){
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<8;i++){
    cout<<"Enter guest "<<i+1<< " Enter choice vegeterian/non-vegeterian:  \n";
    cin>>obj[i].name>>obj[i].choice;
   
  }
  cout<<"Table of Guests: \nNAME\tCHOICE\t\n";
  for(i=0;i<8;i++){
    cout<<obj[i].name<<"\t"<<obj[i].choice<<"\t\t"<<"\n";  
  }       
  return 0;
}
```

This creates the list needed in a simple way but I can not figure out how to do the count. I have tried using the if/else statement with the obj variable but it didn't work. Any tips or solutions will be greatly appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Your array size is `2` but you are trying to add `8` items to it. And I have to ask, why not use `std::vector` or `std::array` and `std::string`?

Comment: Iterate through choices, incrementing the corresponding choice.

Comment: Never use `cin >> ` into a `char[]`. If the user enters more characters than you have place for in the `char[]`, the program will write out of bounds and then you'll have _undefined behavior_ which means that it could crash or do something worse.

Comment: Why do you need the count?  It's hard-coded at either 2 or 8.

Comment: Johnny Mopp, I will try using vectors. Thanks man

Comment: Ted Lyngmo and 2pichar thanks for the tips guys

Comment: Thomas Matthews the program has to make a count of the vegetarian/non-vegetarian choices of 8 people and then calculate the total price for everyone. Two different prices are given for the veg /non-veg dishes.